# latex if condition showing up

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

I have a latex template which auto generates a table of contents (my university made this template). They have since changed their formatting requirements but won't offer help in updating the template.

What I need to do is add "{\noindent Chapter \hfill Page\par}" whenever the #2 is = 76. This works, however I see viii = 76 at the top of my table of contents.

my code:

```
\ifnum #2=76
     {\noindent Chapter \hfill Page\par}
 \fi
```

Some of the page numbers are Arabic numerals  (like 1,2,3,...76) and some are Roman numerals (like viii). My thought is that because the table of contents has Roman numerals and Arabic, the ifnum () = () is breaking and just dumping the raw text (viii=76).

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this?

Is there a way to nest my if statement with another check that verifies the #2 is a number before evaluating it?

Thank you very much!

def code:

```
    \renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
    \newcounter{tocNum}
    \setcounter{tocNum}{76}

  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup

%% My code
       \ifnum #2=76
         {\noindent Chapter \hfill Page\par}
       \fi
    
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode %\bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\dotfill \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue please?

Comment: It might help a bit if you could explain why 76 is special.  Are you supposed to have that at the top of the second chapter?  (BTW, what usually happens is that someone at some point made an unofficial template and it gets passed around.  It would be unusual for a university to actually make the template.)

Comment: Essentially my table of contents is extending to two pages. At the start of a new page I need to have "chapter    page" at the top of the page.  So this ifnum .... adds it for the table of contents item what has page number 76.

Comment: @Mensch, I added the \rnewcommand{...}  is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I think this is what I needed:

\ifstrequal{#2}{76}%
    {
    %my stuff if true
    }

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare *literally* the second argument with `76`.

First: remove the `\newcounter` and `\setcounter` instructions. You don't need that (besides you not wanting to waste a new counter at each call of `\l@chapter`).

Load the `pdftexcmds` package and change the code into

```
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#2}{76}=\z@
  {\noindent Chapter \hfill Page\par}%
\fi
```

`<rant>`
Why should a book have “chapter” and “page” at the top of table of contents pages is something I cannot understand. ***What else*** might those parts be? Are they afraid that whoever reads the thesis is illitterate? Or that the thesis advisor (not illitterate, I presume) will mistake the numbers as the amount of money the student should pay for the chapters?
`</rant>`

Comment: lol, I agree 100% with your rant. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate the `\ifnum` condition slightly different way:

```
\ifnum 76=0#2 
   {\noindent Chapter \hfill Page\par}
\fi
```

Now, if `#2` is non-numeric parameter then 76 is not equal zero. If it is numeric parameter (e.g. 5) then the test says `\ifnum 76=05` and it is not true. But `\ifnum 76=076` returns true.